# choosing the xml path for multiple nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I have my XML structure as below:

```
<Children>
  <Stand>
    <Basics>
      <Attribute Name="Name">User1</Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="Scope">LOCAL</Attribute>
    </Basics>
    <Attributes/>
    <Relationship>
      <Attribute Name="Quantity">2</Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="good Quantity">0</Attribute>
    </Relationship>
  </Stand>
  <Stand>
    <Basics>
      <Attribute Name="Name">User2</Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="Scope">LOCAL</Attribute>
    </Basics>
    <Attributes/>
    <Relationship>
      <Attribute Name="Quantity">5</Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="good Quantity">0</Attribute>
    </Relationship>
  </Stand>
</Children>
```

I want to extract `Name`, `Scope`, `Quantity` and `good Quantity` from the above XML. I am using the Xpath expression:

```
//Children/Stand/* [self::Basics | self::Relationship]
```

The result I am getting is:

```
User1   LOCAL   null   null
null    null    2      0
User2   LOCAL   null   null
null    null    5      0
```

I want result in below way:

```
User1   LOCAL   2      0
User2   LOCAL   5      0
```

Can anyone help to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question has something else besides xpath, because xpath only capable of returning nodes or a primitive type like string, something like that, not a table structured result.

Speaking in xpath only point of view, your current xpath selects both `<Basics>` and `<Relationship>` elements, each of them in a separate row in your result table. I believe you want the xpath to select `<Stand>` elements instead :

```
//Children/Stand
```

and then do columns selection relative to current `<Stand>` element :

```
Basics/Attribute[@Name="Name"]
Basics/Attribute[@Name="Scope"]
Relationship/Attribute[@Name="Quantity"]
Relationship/Attribute[@Name="good Quantity"]
```

This way, all `<Attribute>` elements that corresponds to the same `<Stand>` ancestor are displayed in the same row in the result table.

Comment: I am using XML sequence and extract the values mentioned above. I am attaching my code below for your reference. I tried the way you have mentioned and its not working.

SELECT   
extract(value(MN), '/Basics/Attribute [@Name="Name"]/text()').getStringVal() AS Module_Name,
extract(value(MN), '/Relationship/Attribute[@Name="Configured Quantity"]/text()').getStringVal() AS Quantity,
extract(value(MN), '/Basics/Attribute [@Name="Scope"]/text()').getStringVal() AS Scope
FROM   table A, 
table(xmlsequence(extract(XMLTYPE(A.XML_INFO), '//Children/Stand/[self::Basics | self::Relationship] '))) MN

Comment: @narendragc make sure you post it in the question, not in comment (just in case)

Comment: @narendragc Please read my previous comment. Anyway, try to change xpath for `xmlsequence(...)` part to `//Children/Stand` maybe? It would also helpful for comparison if you post the initial query (before you attempt to apply my suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered applying a scripting language? Because what I'd do is something like this, in `perl` using the rather excellent `XML::Twig` library for XML parsing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub print_user {
    my ( $twig, $stand ) = @_;

    print join( "\t",
        $stand->get_xpath( './Basics/Attribute[@Name="Name"]',     0 )->text,
        $stand->get_xpath( './Basics/Attribute[@Name="Scope"]',    0 )->text,
        $stand->get_xpath( './Relationship/Attribute[@Name="Quantity"]', 0 )->text,
        $stand->get_xpath( './Relationship/Attribute[@Name="good Quantity"]', 0 )
            ->text,
        ),
        "\n";
}

XML::Twig->new( 'twig_handlers' => { 'Stand' => \&print_user } ) -> parsefile ('xmlfile');
```

Or if you'd prefer a little more concise (and assuming the attributes are ordered the same way):

```
use XML::Twig;
XML::Twig->new( 'twig_handlers' => { 'Stand' => sub { print "\n" },
                                     'Attribute' => sub { print $_ -> text,"\t" } } )
    ->parsefile ( 'your_file_name.xml' );
```